# Using the Android Api, how to retrieve entire file path?

Tags: box-api

Given a com.box.androidlib.Utils.BoxUtils.BoxFolder  object, I would like to recurse the object’s parent folders to retrieve the path from the root.

I would hope to do this with something like the below code, where currentBoxFolder is retrieved using Box.getAccountTree(…) as done in the Browse class of the included sample code.  However, the getParentFolder returns null (for non-root folders for which I expect it to be non-null).

I figure that it might be possible to populate the parent variable by modfiying the source to fetch additional attributes, but I was able to.  Any suggestions?

```
List<BoxFolder> parentDirs = new ArrayList<BoxFolder>();
parentDirs.add(new BoxFolderEntry(currentBoxFolder));

BoxFolder parent = currentBoxFolder.getParentFolder();
while(parent != null)
{
    parentDirs.add(0, parent);
    parent = parent.getParentFolder();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the end goal is for you to know the path from the root to a folder, there are a couple ways to solve this:

OPTION 1:

Maintain your own map of folder_ids and folder_names as your application fetches them. Presumably, in order to get the id of currentBoxFolder, you would have had to do getAccountTree() calls on all its parents before-hand.  So if that's the case, you could maintain 2 maps:

Folder ID => Parent Folder ID

Folder ID => Folder Name

From those two maps, you should always be able to get the path from the root.

OPTION 2:

There are 2 params that can be added to the Box.getAccountTree() method that will allow you to know the path:

"show_path_ids"

"show_path_names"

These params haven't been documented yet (we'll do that), but they will cause BoxFolder.getFolderPathIds() and BoxFolder.getFolderPath() to return values such as:

"/5435/4363"

"/blue folder/green folder"

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I would much prefer to use options 2 (because users will be able to jump to folders in a way that won't allow me to cache the path).  Is it possible that this answer refers to params and methods that are not currently available?  When I add these two params, the getFolderPathIds() method returns "" and the BoxFolder.getFolderPath() method does not exist.  Also, in the BoxFolder.parsAttribute() method I see a conditional concerned with "folder_path_ids" but not for either of the strings you specified.

Comment: a) Yes, sorry. Some of these methods/params were in fact pending a push on our side. I've just pushed to github so you should see them now if you grab the latest from master branch. 

b) By any chance, when you saw the empty string for getFolderPathIds(), were you looking at a folder at the root level? Only when looking at folders deeper down will getFolderPathIds() return a non-empty string. If the string is empty, it means the folder is at the root level. The same applies to getFolderPath(). Try running these methods on a folder deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: Possibly I was looking at a root level folder.  After grabbing the latest version, everything works as expected using the params and methods in your answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: With the current version of the api, is there a param I can set such that BoxFolder.getParentFolderId() will return the parent folder's id?  I have tried adding "parent_folder_id" and "show_parent_folder_id", but the return getParentFolderId() remains '-1'.  (I realize I can parse the parent folder's Id from the array returned by BoxFolder.getParentFolderIds(), but would rather use the appropriate method if it is an option.)  Thanks again.